# What is the jurisdiction of the Green Lantern Corps?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Oa is the central hub for the Green Lantern Corps as well as the house for the Central Battery and Book of Oa. It is also said to be the center of the Universe.

From [this wiki](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Oa) (which is the only place I've been able to find a location for Oa) it says that it's in the Milky Way Galaxy. Relatively close to Earth.

What is the distance from Earth to Oa?

Do the Green Lanterns protect the ENTIRE Universe, or just the obervable Universe (about 93 billion light years from the point of origin)?

How large are the sectors?

Were these questions ever asnswered in DC's Universe?

Comment: The sectors are big.  Bigger than that.  Even bigger.  Keep going.  Look, you might think it's a long walk down to the chemist's, but that's peanuts compared to the sectors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Their jurisdiction (prior to the new 52 that started this month) was the entire known universe*.  The Guardians split the universe into 3600 sectors with Oa at the center, and each sector being a wedge radiating out from Oa (this is based on a map they had in a Green Lantern special issue a few years ago).  I don't think there's a known distance between Earth and Oa.

However, Green Lanterns have no issue also policing other universes, as Green Lanterns have from time to time visited the anti-matter universe and some of the other 52 universes.  While there they performed their usual crime-fighting duties, even though they're technically not in their assigned sector.

- "Entire" meaning everything excluding a couple of special cases:

  - Ysmault, located in Sector 2814 is off-limits to Green Lanterns.
  - Sector 3601, which is uninhabitable by organic life.  Beware, Manhunters live here!
  - The [Unknown Sectors](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Unknown_Sectors), which are areas in the universe the Guardians decided shouldn't be protected by the Corps.

Comment: There *are* sections in the universe that are off-limits to the Lanterns, like Ysmault: http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Ysmault . It was during a breach on this planet that the Blackest Night was prophesied to Abin Sur.

Comment: What's Sector 3601? I read something about that, but it seemed to not really go with the rest of the continuity.

Comment: @Oghma: 3601 is where Biot (the planet of the manhunters is).  It's not a nice place, and no one goes there if they can avoid it.

Comment: Updated to cover the parts that aren't in 'entire'.

Comment: Don't forget Vega!  The home of the Orange Light was off-limits to the Corps for a very long time, until the lead-up to Blackest Night.

Answer (score 0):

Vega, where Orange Agent lives is out of GL jurisdiction i suppose.

> > Warning. Vega system off limits to Lanterns. Turn around. Failure to
> >     comply is a court-martial offense. Warning. Turn around.
>
> - Green Lantern ring.